# Matching a string against a list of words

Tags: regex, perl, arrays

Say I have the string "i zipped the fezz and it blipped like a baa" and I have an array of words (moo, baa, zip, fjezz, blaa) that I wanted to test to see it they're contained in the string, is there a way of doing so without either using | in the regex or iterating over each word?

TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using Perl 5.10, you can use the [smart match](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail) operator:

```
my @words = qw/moo bar zip fjezz blaa/;
if ( @words ~~ $str ) { 
    # it's there
}
```

The above will do an equality check (equivalent to `grep $_ eq $str, @words`). If you want a regex match, you can use

```
if ( @words ~~ /$str/ )
```

Otherwise, you're stuck with `grep` or `first` from [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/List::Util):

```
if ( grep { $str =~ /$_/ } @words ) { 
    ...
}
```

Comment: `grep { $str =~ /$_/ } @words` should be `grep { $_ =~ /$str/ } @words`

Comment: Can you still extract matches when using grep? i.e.

    if (grep { $str =~ /(\d+)($_)/ } @words) {
        found "1: $1\n2: $2\n";
    }

A quick try doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Sparkles where did the `\d+` come from?

Comment: @Sparles and what would expect `$1` and `$2` to hold once `grep` is finished checking the match against every element of `@words`?

Comment: In 5.10.1 there have been some changes to smart match.  For eg. if (@words ~~ $str) will no longer work.  It needs to be if ($str ~~ @words).  Strangely if (@words ~~ /$str/) still works!  ref: http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5101delta.html#Smart-match-changes & http://perltraining.com.au/tips/2009-09-07.html

Answer (score 0):

Given your desire to extract the matches as you indicate in a comment to @friedo's answer, I am confused as to why you want to avoid alternation:

```
use strict; use warnings;

use Regex::PreSuf;

my $str = 'i zipped the fezz and it blipped like a baa';

my $re = presuf(qw(moo baa zip fjezz blaa));

my @matches = $str =~ /($re)/g;

print "@matches\n";
```

Output:

```
zip baa
```

Or, do you want the words in the original sentence that match?

```
use strict; use warnings;

use Regex::PreSuf;

my $re = presuf(qw(moo baa zip fjezz blaa));

my $str = 'i zipped the fezz and it blipped like a baa';

my @matches = grep { /$re/ } split /\s+/, $str;

print "@matches\n";
```

Output:

```
zipped baa
```

Comment: Regex::PreSuf shouldn't be used (except perhaps for very long lists) on 5.10 and above; the built-in trie processing is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `grep` or `map` and a *regular expression* to find matches. This brings greater control and flexibility about the matching condition. For example the following code checks if any of the words contained in the list `@words` is found as **an entire word** in the string `$str`:

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $str = "i zipped the fezz and it blipped like a baa";
my @words = qw/moo baa zip fjezz blaa/;

my @found = grep { $str =~ /\b$_\b/ } @words;
if ( @found )  { 
    print join(",", @found) . "\n";
}
```

will output:

```
baa
```

If you are only looking for **partial word matches** in `$str`, drop the word boundary assertions `\b` from the regular expression, i.e. replace the respective line above with the following code:

```
my @found = grep { $str =~ /$_/ } @words;
```

and it will output:

```
baa,zip
```

If you rather want the **words in the original string** '$str' that match, use `map` and modify the regular expression as follows:

```
my @found = map { $str =~ /(\b\w*?$_\w*?\b)/ ? $1 : () ; } @words;
```

will output:

```
baa,zipped
```

I also want to mention the operator `~~` as it described in the accepted answer. If you're using at least Perl 5.10.1, you can use the [smart match](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator) operator to find **entire word** matches. The following code smartmatches each word from string `$str` against the list of words `@words`. The smartmatch will do a comparison based on string equality:

```
my @found = grep { $_ ~~ @words } split(/\s+/, $str) ;
```

and output:

```
Smartmatch is experimental at ./a.pl line 7.
baa
```

The smartmatch operator `~~` was first available in Perl 5.10.1. Starting with Perl 5.18, [smartmatch has been marked as experimental](http://blogs.perl.org/users/mike_b/2013/06/a-little-nicer-way-to-use-smartmatch-on-perl-518.html) and if you use it, a warning will be issued to this effect. Additionally, smartmatch behavior has changed between 5.10.0 and 5.10.1. The code example provided in the "*accepted answer*" is based on 5.10.0 syntax which is obsolete (see dreagtun's comment).

**Note:** You therefore might consider smartmatching as a "non stable" Perl feature.

**PS:** At first, I rewrote the accepted answer but my changes were rejected as being too drastic. Therefore I posted my own answer.